# Campo alfanumérico auto incremental

Tags: sql-server

Mi duda surge a raíz de que me gustaría crear una función que me permita hacer un campo auto incremental con carácteres alfanuméricos como por decir un ejemplo:

> cl0001 cl0002 etc...

Puesto que tengo una tabla de clases y quiero que cada vez que agregue una clase, automáticamente me inserte dicho dato en la columna `'clases'` de mi tabla.

Adjunto la estructura de mi tabla:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Clases](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [salon_id] [int] NULL,
    [profesor_id] [int] NULL,
    [grupo_id] [int] NULL,
    [clase_nom] [varchar](15) NULL,
    [fecha_inic] [datetime] NULL,
    [fecha_fin] [datetime] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK__clases__3213E83F564AFFBF] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
```

Agradezco cualquier tipo de información.

Comment: no se como sera el caso que trabajas, pero me parece que no es correcto. Si la tabla se llama "clases" su id puede ser autonumerico (sin cl), ya que sabes que ese id es de esa tabla. Si vas a tener varios elementos (por ej, aulas, clases, tutorias) realmente necesitas un campo Discriminante, que sera el que tenga el `cl`, `au`, `tu`, por ej. Creo que seria bueno que dieras una vuelta a eso, para no aumentar complejidad de mantenimiento

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Puedes hacer lo que buscas de diferentes formas, visto lo que quieres conseguir, creo que lo más sencillo para ti seria hacer un campo **numérico autoincremental** y cuando obtengas los datos añadir `cl` al número con la cantidad de 0 que pertoquen:

```
"cl" + "000" + "1" -> "cl0001"
```

Tu segunda opción es crear lo que estás pidiendo realmente, que es el campo `varchar` o `nvarchar` autoincremental, el cual puedes crear de la siguiente forma:

```
CREATE TABLE [Clases](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [salon_id] [int] NULL,
    [profesor_id] [int] NULL,
    [grupo_id] [int] NULL,
    [clase_nom] AS ('cl' + RIGHT('0000' + CAST(Id AS VARCHAR(4)), 4)) PERSISTED,
    [fecha_inic] [datetime] NULL,
    [fecha_fin] [datetime] NULL )
```

Lo que hace es partir del campo `Id` y le añade los `'0'` necesarios para que sea un número de 4 dígitos, y le añade los carácteres `'cl'` delante para consolidar tu key alfanumérica.

Si ejecutamos los siguientes `inserts` nos da los resultados siguientes:

```
insert into Clases (salon_id, profesor_id, grupo_id) VALUES (1,1,1);
insert into Clases (salon_id, profesor_id, grupo_id) VALUES (2,2,2);
```

---

```
id  salon_id    profesor_id     grupo_id    clase_nom   fecha_inic  fecha_fin
1   1           1               1           cl0001      (null)      (null)
2   2           2               2           cl0002      (null)      (null)
```

Te dejo el Fiddle donde he hecho las pruebas: [enlace](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/f7a11/1)